# Xcode 7 does not correctly display the size of the view controllers Pagesheet

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, xcode7, uistoryboard, xcode-storyboard

Xcode 7 does not properly resize a PageSheet View Controller in the Storyboard: it always shows the dimensions in full screen.

Is there a solution?

Here you see in the image as to the right is set to the correct size, the view controller should be about half of what is shown now.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: If you use size classes, this is normal behaviour.

Comment: But I disabled the size classes

Comment: Disabling size classes was a bad move.  Note that modal view controllers must be designed in Any/Any, or they will not present correctly.

Comment: my application is designed for running on iPad only, not on iPhone